# using net user multilanguage language

Tags: powershell, multilingual

I am setting up a bunch of computers, and for this i am using powershell.
To setup admin accounts, i have used the net command, but as I get some pc's with danish OS and some with english the commands differ slightly.

Danish version:
`net localgroup Administratorer username /add`

english version:
`net localgroup Administrators username /add`

This means i need two versions of the script. is it possible to take another aproach? perhaps using some ID to identify the admin group? like writing 3334 instead of administator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The builtin Administrators group may indeed have different names depending on the installation language, but the group's security identifier is always the same:

> ```
> S-1-5-32-544
> ```

To find the local name, use WMI:

```
$AdminGroupName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group -Filter 'LocalAccount = True AND SID = "S-1-5-32-544"').Name
```

Now you can do:

```
net localgroup $AdminGroupName username /add
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to leverage the .NET framework (via Powershell) to retrieve the localized name of the administrators group. I find it better than hardcoding the SID of the administrators group, even though it never changes.

```
$adminGroupSid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::BuiltinAdministratorsSid,$null)
$adminGroupName = $adminGroupSid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).ToString()
$adminsName = ($adminGroupName -split "\\")[1]
```

From then on, you can either use `$adminsName` when calling `net localgroup`

```
net localgroup $adminsname /add <user>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I am choosing Mathias for a more oneliner solution, but thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to run it as a package in SCCM without content folder

```
%windir%\Sysnative\windowsPowershell\V1.0\powershell -command "$an='AdminUser';$ap='password'; net user /add $an $ap; $agn = (gwmi -Class Win32_Group -Filter 'LocalAccount=True AND SID="""S-1-5-32-544"""').Name;net localgroup $agn $an /add"
```